# How do you view available shortcuts on confluence?

Tags: wiki, confluence

Confluence allows you to use shortcuts, so for example you could have [confluence@Google] to link to http://www.google.com/search?q=confluence

However, I can't seem to find a listing of all available shortcuts anyone on my confluence install (I'm not an administrator and I'd rather not bother the admin if possible).

So how do you get a list of all available shortcuts?

Edit: To be clear I am looking for **link** shortcuts, not **keyboard** shortcuts.

Comment: Good question (+1) - for reference regarding your edit: [Configuring Shortcut Links](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+Shortcut+Links) provides the related documentation and includes more detailed examples of this feature as well (for those unaware of it still).

Comment: Ah yes, linking to the actual documentation would have been an excellent way to communicate exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This obvious feature still seems to be unavailable as of today, see the following related improvement requests within the [Confluence issue tracker](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF):

- Oldest: [List shortcut links in notation guide](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-3630)
- Duplicate: [[...], is it possible to display the actual shortcut keys for that Confluence instance? ([...])](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-7557)
- **Most relevant**: [Links Browser: Should provide visibility of available shortcut links](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-18565)

The latter in particular is kind of unfortunate, because its description addresses the topic precisely:

> Shortcut Links  are a massively useful
>   feature of Confluence, but one that is
>   largely unknown and unused by users as
>   it is not easily discoverable.
>
> Currently, shortcut links are
>   configured by admin users on an
>   admin-only screen, and there is no way
>   for non-admin users to see what
>   shortcuts are available.

The mentioned *[redesign of the links browser](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-14875)* has been implemented as of version 3.2 and is indeed a major improvement in various areas, but the [obvious addition](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-18565) you (and others, including me now ;) desire has apparently been scrapped from version 3.3 without further explanation so far.

So I'm afraid bothering your administrator is still the most straight forward option to get a list of all available shortcuts right now; obviously you could vote for the feature(s) and/or ask why they have been unscheduled resp. whether/when it might get rescheduled within the Atlassian tracker as well.

---

**Update:**

Apparently it might be possible to workaround the lack of this feature in Confluence by developing a new (or fixing an existing) plugin based upon the [Atlassian Plugin SDK](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEVNET/Atlassian+Plugin+SDK), see harrymcs answer for more on this.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the correct answer. I hope they fix it in newer releases. Luckily my company is small and talking to the admin is very easy, I was more interested out of principle, although it's always nice not to have to bother people too much.

Comment: I didn't realize that awarding the bounty was separate from accepting an answer.

Comment: @Bostonvaulter - yeah, that's kind of counter intuitive at first sight, so thanks much for realizing and awarding it before the bounty period expired (I already forgot about it myself, with only one up vote currently I would have pinged you otherwise to avoid loosing it entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a user of Confluence, but this article may help:
[Shortcut-list macro broken in newer versions of Confluence](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/browse/PLINF-2)

> The `shortcut-list` macro which is
>   shipped together with the [Plugins
>   Information plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Plugins+Information+Plugin), returns a
>   result similar to the following when
>   the macro is used in Confluence
>   version 2.3.1:
>
> [image]

If this macro interests you, then read also the comments for the above article.

Comment: Interesting indeed, thanks for digging it up (+1) - so it at least looks like one might be able to build a new or updated plugin including the desired functionality based upon the current [Atlassian Plugin SDK](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEVNET/Atlassian+Plugin+SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Keyboard+Shortcuts

**All Screens**

Keystroke   Action

Alt-Q   Quick search field

Alt-S   Submit (where a form is active)

**Rich Text Editor Screen**

Keystroke   Action

Ctrl-(1-6)  Applies a heading style (of the number chosen) to the current line

Ctrl+Shift+A    Opens the macro browser

Ctrl-B  Makes the selected text bold

Ctrl+Shift+B    Formats text as a bullet list

Ctrl-I  Makes the selected text italic

Ctrl-K  Inserts a link (opens insert link dialog)

Ctrl+Shift+K    Autocomplete for links. Calls up a list of suggested pages or other locations to link to from your page. More...

Ctrl-M  Insert Image (opens insert image dialog)

Ctrl+Shift+M    Autocomplete for embedding images and files. Calls up a list of suggested images, documents and other files to embed in your page. More...

Ctrl+Shift+N    Formats text as a numbered list

Ctrl+Shift+S    Formats text with a strike through

Ctrl-U  Makes the selected text underlined

Ctrl-Y  Revert an action that was undone

Ctrl-Z  Undo the most recent action

Tab     Indents current line only in bullet lists and numbered lists

Shift+Tab   'Outdents' current line only in bullet lists and numbered lists

**Tables in the Rich Text Editor:**

Ctrl+Shift+C    Copies a table row

Ctrl+Shift+X    Cuts a table row

Ctrl+Shift+V    Pastes a table row

Ctrl+Shift+I    Inserts a table

> Safari users please note: In the Rich
>   Text Editor, the shortcut keys for
>   bold, italic and underline do not
>   currently work. See CONF-13555. Cmd-B
>   and Cmd-I currently toggle bold and
>   italic formatting.

**Login Screen**

Alt-U   Username field

Alt-P   Password field

Alt-R   Check 'Remember Me'

**View Screen**

Alt-A   Attachments View

Alt-E   Edit Page

Alt-I   Information View

Alt-M   Add Comment

**Add Page Screen**

Alt-A   Add Page

Alt-P   Preview Page

Alt-S   Save button

**Edit Page Screen**

Alt-U   Update Page

Alt-P   Preview Page

Alt-S   Save button

**Modifier Keys**

The modifier key will differ with each operating system and browser. For example, when running Firefox 3 on Windows, you will need to type 'Alt' + 'Shift' + 'E' to edit a page. The following table shows the modifier keys for the various combinations:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, no I am looking for link shortcuts not keyboard shortcuts.